# How to check that the passed Iterator is a random access iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have the following code, which does some iterator arithmetic:

```
template<class Iterator>
void Foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
  typedef typename Iterator::value_type Value;
  std::vector<Value> vec;
  vec.resize(last - first);
  // ...
}
```

The `(last - first)` expression works (AFAIK) only for random access iterators (like the ones from `vector` and `deque`). How can I check in the code that the passed iterator meets this requirement?

Comment: You could avoid the check altogether by using `distance(first, last)`.

Comment: This might work for your specific use cases, but in general, you can't rely on the 'random access' tag to say that the memory that the iterator points to is sequential.  Look at the documentation of Microsoft's concurrent_vector class.  Random access only means that you have a [] operator that the iterator understands.  Also, how to handle reverse iterators, which are random access?  I have a similar question that I posted looking for an answer here: [Filtering Iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064481/filtering-specific-iterators-for-template-functions/)

Comment: @KentKnox: Who said anything about the memory being sequential?  `last-first` works on all random access iterators, including `std::deque::iterator`, which is _definitely_ not pointing to sequential memory.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If `Iterator` is a random access iterator, then

```
std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category
```

will be `std::random_access_iterator_tag`.  The cleanest way to implement this is probably to create a second function template and have `Foo` call it:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void FooImpl(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::random_access_iterator_tag) { 
    // ...
}

template <typename Iterator>
void Foo(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category category;
    return FooImpl(first, last, category());
}
```

This has the advantage that you can overload `FooImpl` for different categories of iterators if you'd like.

Scott Meyers discusses this technique in one of the *Effective C++* books (I don't remember which one).

Comment: Indeed, this is precisely the technique used by `std::distance` in the g++ implementation I'm looking at (4.3.2)

Comment: @Fred and `std::advance()` too.

Comment: Other options include (a) adding a no-op capabilities check (e.g. `first + 0;`), (b) using explicit template specialization, or (c) overloading with SFINAE.  However, I don't think any of these are as clean or straightforward as the tag dispatching approach.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the tag dispatch, you can compare the category to `std::random_access_iterator_tag` directly using [`std::is_same_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
using category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category;
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>) {
  vec.resize(last - first);
}
```

This can sometimes lead to a more clear and concise code, particularly if only a small part of your implementation (like reserving the vector size) depends on the iterator category.

Comment: One could use `static_assert` if a non random access iterator would be an error. Also I would consider `std::is_convertible_v` instead of `std::is_same_v` as the former allows the possibility of some future version of C++ to have another type tag that is also a `std::random_access_iterator_tag` via inheritance. Iterator tags already use inheritance to express the is-a relationship.

Comment: I definitely like this answer more, if only because the primary reason I wanted to use it when I was looking for this was a microoptimization to determine whether I could cheaply compute the size to `reserve` (not even `resize`) in a `vector`, for an algorithm that would happily work with any forward iterator otherwise. Didn't want to end up traversing, say, a `std::list` twice, once to compute a `reserve` size, then again to populate the `vector` based on it, when I could just rely on amortized growth. Factoring out that single line of code into a whole new function would be a pain.

Comment: @Araeos You're right about inheritance, but then why not use `std::is_base_of_v<RequiredTag, ActualTag>`? That's clearer that tags use inheritance for hierarchy, not only convertibility.