# meta function with default behavior on missing trait and how to detect random access

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

The following meta-function computes if a given type is a random access iterator:

```
    template <class I>
    struct is_random_access
        : boost::is_convertible
        < typename boost::iterator_traversal<I>::type
        , boost::random_access_traversal_tag
        >
    {};
```

Now of course, this doesn't work if `I` is not an iterator at all, as there is no `boost::iterator_traversal<I>` is defined.

Two independent questions:

1. How to make `is_random_access` return false (rather than fail to compile) when `I` is not an iterator?
2. Is this a good way to detect if an iterator is random access traverseable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307271/how-to-check-that-the-passed-iterator-is-a-random-access-iterator

Comment: 1. i don't want to tag dispatch. i want the meta-function as asked, to work.
2. isn't std::random_access_iterator_tag a subset of random_access_traversal_tags (i.e. there are random access traversal iterators which aren't std::random_access_iterator_tag)?

Comment: Something like `std::conditional<has_type<boost::iterator_traversal<I>>::value, identity<is_random_access<I>>, identity<identity<std::false_type>>>::type::type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question you can actually use the [SFINEA example from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
template <class... Ts> using void_t = void;

template <class I, class = void>
    struct is_random_access: boost::false_type
    {};

template <class I>
    struct is_random_access<I,void_t<typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category> >
        : boost::is_convertible
        <typename boost::iterator_traversal<I>::type, boost::random_access_traversal_tag>
    {};
```

If the input type does not have the `iterator_category` type defined, it will fall back to the default struct, if it is defined, it will use your specialization.

For the second question I am no expert. However, my interpretation agrees with yours: for every iterator with `std::random_access_iterator_tag`, the `boost::iterator_traversal<>::type` will be convertible to `boost::random_access_traversal_tag`.

---

Update: Fixed the problem that int* is not regcognized as a valid iterator. Replaced `I:iteratory_category` by `std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category`.

Comment: Thanks many, this is pretty neat. I didn't know about `void_t<..>` technique and it is very useful. Unfortunately, this solution does not quite work.  We can not use `I::iterator_category`,  since we want also e.g. `is_random_access<int*>` to be valid and be true. So it has to be `boost::iterator_traversal<T>::type`, however, sfinae doesn't quite work like that (change to that to see the error)

Comment: Thanks for the updated message. For the record, `std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category` does indeed work, and `boost::iterator_traversal<T>::type` does not, which is a rather obscure thing apparently about an already obscure sfinae pattern.