# Is there a way to check if an iterator is random_access within an IF statement in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

Creating a templated overload for the function in question isn't a workable solution due to size, so is there a way to check if an iterator is random access without using templates and enable_if, etc???

eg - something like:

```
if (std::iterator_traitzzz<it>::the_type == random_access_yo)
{ 
   DO THE THING
}
```

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994437/4123703) is the canon one, I think, though R Sahu's one below is also good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check that the passed Iterator is a random access iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307271/how-to-check-that-the-passed-iterator-is-a-random-access-iterator)

Comment: Sorry for mis-flag. I've add another flag for explaining it. Could you add the template post and indicate it's not the solution you want?

Comment: @LouisGo Sorry, entirely my bad - I didn't read the second answer on that page and missed the non-template answer. Feel free to re-flag as duplicate, but R Sahu's solution also works for this, although it misfires when make_move_iterator is used on a non-random_access iterator.

Comment: Do you mean this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994437/4123703 You may edit your post to include the linke, because your question would be easier for searching.

Comment: Good point - I will.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
template< class, class = void >
struct is_random_access_itertor : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct is_random_access_itertor<T,
           std::void_t<decltype(T()+10), decltype(*T())>> : std::true_type { };
```

to deduce whether `T` is a random access iterator. It uses two characteristics of random access iterator types to make the deduction.

1. `T() + 10` is a valid expression.
2. `*T()` is a valid expression.

You may add other characteristics of radom access iterators to make the deduction more robust.

Now, you can use

```
if constexpr ( is_random_access_itertor<decltype(it)>::value )
{
   // Yes, it is a random access iterator.
}
```

Comment: Very good answer, however it misfires when used on an iterator generated from a non-random_access iterator by std::make_move_iterator. Not sure what's missing there.
Considering the second answer in the linked (duplicate) question the winner here as it's more concise, but this is a close second.